# What makes the first 3 alkanes decrease in melting point while after that they rise?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, melting-point

What makes the first 3 alkanes decrease in melting point (m.p.) while after that they rise?

$$
\begin{array}{lr}
\hline
\text{Alkane} & \text{m.p.}/\pu{°C} \\
\hline
\text{Methane} & -182 \\
\text{Ethane}  & -183 \\
\text{Propane} & -188 \\
\text{Butane}  & -138 \\
\text{Pentane} & -130 \\
\text{Hexane}  & -95  \\
\text{Heptane} & -91  \\
\text{Octane}  & -57  \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: It is packing . After the first terms then molecular surface takes the leading role.  Perhaps someone will articulate in a more complete form but the juice is this.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/89689/for-two-compounds-that-are-symmetrical-why-does-the-more-compact-one-have-a-hig https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71417/why-alkanes-containing-even-number-of-carbons-can-be-packed-more-efficiently-tha